# Selecting elements from filter table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, select, button

I have the following code to create a table of employees which allows me to filter through them based on a query term:

I want to add html buttons that would be included along with the employee in the table so I can add a

`<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>`

which would allow me to then create and add employees to a new list of selected employees [Image of elements I want to add](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivc1O.png) I am not sure if this is possible to do so I'm asking for some help here. Alternatively, if it is not possible to add this HTML element into the table how would I go about modifying the code so if I clicked on a row of the filtered table it would allow me to select that row and then add it to the new list of selected employees.

Thanks so much!

```
<style>
    th{ 
        cursor: pointer;
        color:#fff;
            }
</style>

<div class="row">
    <div class ="col">
        <div class="card card-body">

            <input id="search-input" class="form-control" type="text">

        </div>

    </div>

</div>


<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr  class="bg-info">
        <th  class="bg-info" data-colname="name" data-order="desc">Name &#9650</th>
        <th  data-colname="age" data-order="desc">Age &#9650</th>
        <th  data-colname="birthdate" data-order="desc">Birthday &#9650</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody id="myTable">

    </tbody>
</table>




<script>
var myArray = [
    {'name':'Michael', 'age':'30', 'birthdate':'11/10/1989'},
    {'name':'Mila', 'age':'32', 'birthdate':'10/1/1989'},
    {'name':'Paul', 'age':'29', 'birthdate':'10/14/1990'},
    {'name':'Dennis', 'age':'25', 'birthdate':'11/29/1993'},
    {'name':'Tim', 'age':'27', 'birthdate':'3/12/1991'},
    {'name':'Erik', 'age':'24', 'birthdate':'10/31/1995'},
]

$('#search-input').on('keyup', function(){
    var value= $(this).val()
    console.log('value:', value)
    var data = searchTable(value, myArray)
    buildTable(data)

})


buildTable(myArray)

function searchTable(value, data){

    var filteredData = []

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        value = value.toLowerCase()
        var name = data[i].name.toLowerCase()
        var age = data[i].age.toLowerCase()
        var birthdate = data[i].age.toLowerCase()

        if(name.includes(value)){
            filteredData.push(data[i])

        }
        else if(age.includes(value)){
            filteredData.push(data[i])

        } 
        else if(birthdate.includes(value)){
            filteredData.push(data[i])

        }
    }
    return filteredData

}



 $('th').on('click', function(){
     var column = $(this).data('colname')
     var order = $(this).data('order')
     var text = $(this).html()
     text = text.substring(0, text.length - 1);



     if (order == 'desc'){
        myArray = myArray.sort((a, b) => a[column] > b[column] ? 1 : -1)
        $(this).data("order","asc");
        text += '&#9660'
     }else{
        myArray = myArray.sort((a, b) => a[column] < b[column] ? 1 : -1)
        $(this).data("order","desc");
        text += '&#9650'
     }

    $(this).html(text)
    buildTable(myArray)
    })





function buildTable(data){
    var table = document.getElementById('myTable')
    table.innerHTML = ''
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        var colname = `name-${i}`
        var colage = `age-${i}`
        var colbirth = `birth-${i}`

        var row = `<tr>
                        <td>${data[i].name}</td>
                        <td>${data[i].age}</td>
                        <td>${data[i].birthdate}</td>
                   </tr>`
        table.innerHTML += row
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: I didn't understand it very well. Do you want to add buttons to a certain row in the table using filtering (input)?

Comment: Only that? "I want to add html buttons that would be filtered along with the employee in the table so I can add a"

Comment: Reading it back it is unclear, the desired change is to add a button into the row.

Comment: You can do this using the 'myArray' object, add a 'button' object for example to 'myArray' and enter the text for that button. Then go to the function responsible for creating the table (buildTable) and then add a `<td> <button> $ {data [i] .button} </button> </td>`